# Changing views from an inner adapter?

Tags: java, android, gridview, baseadapter

This is my first post and I hope I won't make any mistakes writing it. I am in the process of making my own application, and I got stuck at this point.

I have a GridView with a custom layout, which has two views on top of each other (an ImageButton and an overlay, so to speak). I was trying to implement something that sounds like this: when I click on the Button, some views on the Activity would change:

```
//listener code goes here

title.setText("Title");
description.setText("Description);
preview.setAlpha(1.0f);
lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

After a lot of failed attempts of trying to implement the `OnItemClickListener()`, I took the conclusion that I need to implement a `OnClickListener()` on the button in the BaseAdapter. However, I don't know how I can possibly do that.

I've tried a lot of things, like implementing a method on the Activity class to change them and then call it. I got a non-static error. I've also tried implementing an AsyncTask that checks for changes in a static variable in the Activity every 100ms. (That worked only once and then stopped) It works fine now. It was something like this:

```
 public class UpdateChecker extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(selected)
            {
                Start();
                selected = false;
            }


            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The OnClickListener was like:

```
     viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view)
     {
         CustomizeActivity.currId =  TargetManager.getTarget(position).ID;
         CustomizeActivity.selected = true;
         CustomizeActivity.currpos = position;
     }
 });
```

(The values set are static)

XML:

> 

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/setButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff191919"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/frameLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:id="@+id/titleView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/preView"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#ffeaeaea"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a sample long description. I am testing."
            android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/preView"
            android:textColor="#ffcdcdcd"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/preView"
            android:src="@drawable/target_hellokitty"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/preView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/preView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/preView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/preView"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <GridView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/gridView"
                        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:columnWidth="100dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Button"
    android:id="@+id/setButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff00a4e1"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

Do you think implementing an ASyncTask as a listener with an infinite loop and a check is a good idea?

Comment: Maybe you should add your xml code here, and we can see it .

Comment: I've added both the preview and the overlay in a framelayout and now it doesn't mess my layout up anymore. However, the image does not load. Is the AsyncTask way a decent solution to my problem?

Comment: AsyncTask is used for 1 or 2 seconds network operations , which means if your image is HQ it may take more time to load and in that case ,using a loader or a service , is much better .

Comment: I meant using an AsyncTask as a listener, and changing a static variable to trigger it.